# TEMP Database is not showing Encrypted in TDE in SQL Server 2008R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016, transparent-data-encryption

As per my knowledge, when we encrypt any user database in SQL Server through TDE, the TEMP database automatically gets encrypted.

I have done TDE in SQL Server 2016, and when I check through SELECT name, is_encrypted FROM sys.databases, it shows user and temp database as 1 (Encrypted).

But when I performed TDE on SQL Server 2008R2 (using same method), and I fired the command, the user database was encrypted, but TEMP database status for 'is_encrypted' is still showing as '0'.

What could be the reason or what wrong has happened?